# How add width div with React?

Tags: reactjs

Add a div and a button. When you click - increase the width of the div by 3 px. Add a Reset button that allows you to reset the state to the initial width.

```
const three = (e) => {
 let value = e.target.value;
 this.setState({ three: value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to define a state variable to toggle and based on its status we can toggle width as well, so our code would be something like this -:

Working demo -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-576vo5?file=index.js

In `js` file -:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={`flexible-width ${this.state.increaseWidth ? "long-width" : "short-width"}`} onClick={() => this.setState({increaseWidth: !this.state.increaseWidth})}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

In `css` file -:

```
.flexible-width{
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
.long-width{
  width: 150px;
}
.short-width{
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple width style do it like this. If you want to do extensive styling, shift to using `CSS` classes and changing classes at runtime.

```
import React from 'react';

class Component extends React.Component {

  state = {
    clicked: false
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div>
      <div style = {{ width: this.state.clicked ? "100px" : "103px" }>
        //div content here
      </div> 
      <button onClick = {() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clcked})}> 
        { clicked ? "Reset" : "Increase Width"} 
      </button>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default Component;
```